# Mysql 2 select staments with value from statement 1 used in statement 2

Tags: mysql, select

How to join these to in one sql statement?
I have these 2 simple tables.

```
3_Referee_Matches
+------------------------------------+
| ID | CountryCode | RefereeUrlCode  |
| 1  |    eng      | mike-jean       |
| 2  |    eng      | mike-jean       |
| 3  |    eng      | mike-jean       |
| 4  |    eng      | mike-jean       |
| 5  |    spa      | hulo-pape       |
| 6  |    ita      | enri-tolsi      |
| 7  |    ita      | enra-ean        |
| 8  |    ita      | enra-ean        |
+------------------------------------+


3_Players
+----------------------------------------------------+
| ID | MatchID |     Name   | PlayerUrlCode | Yellow |
| 1  |    1    | Mike Bell  | mike-bell     |    1   |
| 2  |    2    | Mike Bell  | mike-bell     |    1   |
| 3  |    3    | Thoms Tim  | thoms-tim     |    1   |
| 4  |    4    | Jean Claod | jean-claod    |    0   |
| 5  |    33   | Thoms Tim  | thoms-tim     |    1   |
| 6  |    44   | Fis Most   | fis-most      |    0   |
| 7  |    54   | Geni Toens | geni-toens    |    1   |
| 8  |    67   | Geni Toens | geni-toens    |    1   |
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Today i use these 2 select. But need help to combine them into one.

select 1:

```
SELECT rm.*, p.PlayerUrlCode AS VALUEtoBEusedAGAIN, COUNT(p.ID) AS YellowCounter 
FROM 3_Referee_Matches rm
JOIN 3_Players p ON rm.ID = p.MatchID
WHERE rm.CountryCode = 'eng' AND rm.RefereeUrlCode = 'mike-jean'
AND p.Yellow>0 
GROUP BY p.Name
```

select 2:

```
SELECT COUNT(rm.ID) AS Counter 
FROM 3_Referee_Matches rm 
JOIN 3_Players p ON rm.ID = p.MatchID
WHERE rm.RefereeUrlCode='mike-jean'
AND p.PlayerUrlCode='VALUEtoBEusedAGAIN'
```

Result should be like this:

```
+--------------------------------------+
| Name       | YellowCounter | Counter |
| Mike Bell  |      2        |    2    |
| Jean Claod |      1        |    1    |   
+--------------------------------------+
```

Showing that Mike Bell Got 2 yellow cards in 2 matches.

Comment: can you display the tables in tabular form with some values and your expected results

Comment: Sure. Now ready

Comment: if you want to combine both queries to one use `union` to join them

Comment: @Hirumina i have tried but cant figure it out.

Comment: can you show the expected result using tabular form

Comment: @Hirumina updated with expected result. Thanks

Comment: Your first select does not work, there are too many non-aggregated columns not in the group by clause. Should Thomas Tim have 1 yellow and Jean Claod 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first query is nearly there. First, remove the extraneous columns from the `select` clause. `count` the number of "players" (really player information for each match) and `sum` their yellow cards.

```
select
  p.name,
  sum(yellow) as YellowCounter,
  count(p.id) as Counter
from 3_Referee_Matches rm
join 3_Players p on rm.ID = p.MatchID
where rm.CountryCode = 'eng'
  and rm.RefereeUrlCode = 'mike-jean'
group by p.name;

+------------+---------------+---------+
| name       | YellowCounter | Counter |
+------------+---------------+---------+
| Mike Bell  |             2 |       2 |
| Thoms Tim  |             1 |       1 |
| Jean Claod |             0 |       1 |
+------------+---------------+---------+
```

I assume the example has Thoms and Jean reversed.

Comment: Side question. If i only want to have them with more than 1 match? count(p.id) >0

Comment: @Falslev `having counter > 1`. You can't use aggregate functions like `count` in a `where` clause, that's what [`having`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) is for.